# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (11,)

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train my model with Keras and I'm taking this online course from udemy. Now everything works fine but when I try to fit the ANN to the training set it gives the following error. everything works fine but when I EXECUTE this last line it gives the error.
It should work fine without this error or is there any other way to fit the ANN to the training set?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train , y_train , X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2 , random_state = 0)


#convert X_test into a 'numpy' array to acoid valur error for 1D array 
X_test = np.reshape(y, (-1,1))

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)


import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

#initializing the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

#adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units =6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu', input_dim =11 ))

#adding the second layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6 , kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu'))

#adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1 , kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'sigmoid'))

#compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# 'optimizer' is the algorithm that u wanna use for the wights adjustments

#fitting the ann to the trainging set 
classifier.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size =10 , epochs = 100 )
```

Comment: Since you are using OneHotEncoder, i'm not sure that your input_dim == 11. try: input_dim = X_train.shape[1]

Comment: You must fit StandardScaler only on train data: sc.fit(X_train); X_train = sc.transform(X_train); X_test = sc.transform(X_test). Idem for labelEncoder and OnehotEncoder, you must fit on train data and handle new labels.

Comment: @Amine it still gives the same error .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `input_shape` is not set correctly.

**from [docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/):**

> Input shape
>
> nD tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common
>   situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim).

In your case `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)`

Try this:

```
#initializing the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

#adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=6,
                     kernel_initializer='uniform',
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],))

...
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sir.  Appreciated :)